# GEM Framework, or let's study GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, rubygems

I want to play around with GCC and try to modify it somehow. I've read something about [GEM framework](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_C_Compiler_Internals/GEM_Framework), but everything is from year 2006 or older and every download link is dead. I can't google anything more about it. Is there any current source, or something similar to this tool?
Or do you have any suggestions, where to start? I've started to study its architecture, but I would appreciate some helping tool for a start, reather then studying source code.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: GCC is a *beast*! And it has changed *a lot* since 2006. Your best bet would be to download the current release, and start studying the code. It will take time though, as there is a lot of code, and probably not very straightforward code at times either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about GEM, specifically, but the page you link to suggests it's about *plugins* (although it calls them *extensions*).

Plugins are now an official feature of GCC, so I'd imagine the GEM stuff is obsolete.

Here's some reading material for you:

- [GCC Internals Manual (Plugins section)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)
- [GCC Wiki (Plugins page)](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/plugins)